# How to read multiple random key data from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from firebase in my android app. This is how it looks.
[image: firebase database structure]

I want to read the marked data. I am able to read the key of categories child. But unable to read the ids values.

Here's my code:

```
dbCategories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categories");

dbCategories.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String name = ds.getKey();
                String ids = ds.child("ids").getValue(String.class);

                Log.i(name, "onDataChange: "+ids);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could not connect to the root you want. For example, **tcat2**, you can modify the **ids**.

You **must** specify the path from which you want to read.

> You can try this :

```
dbCategories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categories");

        dbCategories.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                       
                      String name = ds.getKey();
                       
                       for(DataSnapshot ds1 : ds.child(name).child("ids").getChildren()){   

                       String ids = ds1.getValue(String.class);

                        Log.i(name, "onDataChange: "+ids);

                       }

                       
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I hope I helped you.